# In C, how does arithmetic between a pointer and an array work?

Tags: c, pointers

What should be the value of y and why?

```
int x[] = { 1, 4, 8, 5, 1, 4 }; 
int *ptr, y; 
ptr  = x + 4; 
y = ptr - x;
```

I think y should be 4*sizeof(int), but it is giving 4. Why ?

Comment: Why don't you compile it and run it?

Comment: I ran it and I got y as 4 but y is it giving 4, I dont understand

Comment: I thought it was a good question....?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`I think y should be 4*sizeof(int)`

Good thinking, and guess what? It **is** giving `4*sizeof(int)`, but you're not looking at it right. ;)

When you're playing with pointers, you're looking at addresses, so let's check out some addresses

```
int x[] = { 1, 4, 8, 5, 1, 4 };

//Just for fun, what is the address of each element in the array?
printf("%#x, %#x, %#x, %#x, %#x, %#x\n", x+0, x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4, x+5);

ptr = x + 4;

printf("%#x - %#x\n", ptr, x);  // Give us the address of ptr in hex
                                // and give us the address of x
y = ptr - x;                    

printf("%d\n", y);
```

Output:

```
   x[0]         x[1]        x[2]        x[3]         x[4]       x[5]
0xbf871d20, 0xbf871d24, 0xbf871d28, 0xbf871d2c, 0xbf871d30, 0xbf871d34

   ptr           x
0xbf871d30 - 0xbf871d20

4
```

So ptr is `x+4` (which is really `x + 4*sizeof(int)` or `x+16` in your case). And we're going to subtract from that `x` or the base address, so the actual math is `0x30 - 0x20 = 0x10` or in dec `16`.

The reason you're seeing `4` on the output is because the compiler knows you're doing operations on `int *` so it's dividing that `16` by `sizeof(int)` for you. Nice hm?

If you want to see the actual value you need to do something like this:

```
int one, two;
...
one = (int)ptr;  //get the addresses, ignore the "type" of the pointer 
two = (int)x;
y = one - two;
```

Now `y` will give you 0x10(hex) or 16(dec)

Answer (score 7):

It should be the number of int's between the address that points to the start of `x` and the address of x's 4-th element => 4.

From c99 standard:

> **6.5.6 Additive operators**
>
> 9/ When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements.

To find out more, try searching for **pointer arithmetic**.

Answer (score 4):

Just apply some simple algebra

```
if
    ptr = x + 4
and
    y = ptr - x

therefore

y = (x + 4) - x

hence y = 4 + x - x

thus y = 4 + 0 

     y = 4
```

Edit: Addressing the comment

This is C, a ptr is just value of whatever size bits. Adding a number to it (except in the case of overflow) is just some integral number + another integral number (cast to the appropriate size), and thus removing the original number leaves a remainder. Since we only added 4 (smaller than an int) this means that there is no issue implicitly casting it to the y int.

Comment: You lost me further in that second paragraph. To rephrase - if I print out the value of 'x' and the value of 'ptr', the difference is greater than 4. Yet `x - ptr == 4`. It's not just adding a number and taking it away again.

Comment: +1 The same explanation was running through my mind. The pointer arithmetic is not needed here to be considered. It's just set of simple equations problem.

Comment: @sje397 - yes I believe you are just doing integer maths. The pointer aspect IMHO is just a red herring. Of course the C specs could be specific (one hopes) and have this as a particular use case but because it's just C and you're using a number (4) much lower than MAX_INT I can't see how this is nothing more than a implicit integer calc.

Answer (score 2):

if the operands of the binary  '-'
 are both pointers of same type it is evaluated as

> (p-q)/sizeof(type of p or q)

in case the second operand is integer
 then

> p - sizeof(p)*q